# Turn off an app in PowerApps

Tags: office-365, powerapp

Just a simple question, allmost all is in the title.

I would like to know if it's possible to turn off an app in PowerApps without deleting or unsharing it ?

Answer (score 1):

There's no OFF button in PowerApps.

You may suggest it as an idea: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/PowerApps-Ideas/idb-p/PowerAppsIdeas/status-key/Started

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible. Either you will delete or unshare from all users.